# jQuery - If URL matches href then move LI to top of UL?

Tags: jquery

Been trying to get this to work unsuccessfuly. Any help would be appreciated.

Search UL, if any href are equal to the current URL then move it's list item to the top of the UL list stack.

```
var url = window.location.toString();

$('#partnerCharities li.panel h1 a').each(function(){
   var myHref= $(this).attr('href');
   if( url.match( myHref)) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().before("#slider1 li:first");
   }
});
```

It's a dynamically created list (image gallery), so not sure if that's why the jQuery isn't working? This is the rough layout you see in Firebug...

```
<ul id="slider">
 <li class="panel cloned"></li>
 <li class="panel">
  <article>
   <h1><a href="site.com">Example</a></h1>
  </article>
 </li>
 <li class="panel cloned"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mistakes with your code, take a look at a working example i made.

[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kyEhF/1/)

html:

```
<ul id="slider">
 <li class="panel cloned">test1</li>
 <li class="panel">
  <article>
   <h1><a href="site.com">This should come out on top.</a></h1>
  </article>
 </li>
 <li class="panel cloned">test2</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
var url = "site.com"; //or window.location.toString();

$('#slider li.panel h1 a').each(function(){
   var myHref= $(this).attr('href');
   if( url == myHref) {
        $(this).closest("li").prependTo("#slider");
   }
});
```

Comment: Excellent! It was adding the LI in the wrong place (I think because that cloned li is always on top) so I changed it to .insertAfter("#slider1 li:first"); and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question doesn't really state this, I'm going to guess that you're wanting th match the path portion of the `href` to the current `location`.

If so, and the `hrefs` won't have any query string parameters, you should be able to do something like this:

```
 // get the pathname portion of the location
var path = window.location.pathname;

 // get the <a> element whose href ends with the pathname, then get its <li>
var $currentLi = $('#partnerCharities li.panel h1 a[href$=' + path + ']').closest('li');

 // prepend the <li> to the parent of the <li> (which is the <ul>)
$currentLi.prependTo( $currentLi.parent() );
```

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/owuye4/2/

Point is that you probably don't need to iterate over each item.